# Simplify GeoServer WFS output

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, boundless-suite

I am dealing with some large datasets and would like to minimise the amount of data sent over the network. I am using OpenLayers' BBox strategy to only transfer the data that is needed but I am wondering whether I can simplify the output so that I can show lower zoom levels without having to transfer data with unnecessary accuracy/detail.

I am using GeoServer as a WFS server as part of the OpenGeo bundle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WFS/GeoServer does not really provide any way to do generalization on the fly based on scale, but there is a special extension that does what you are looking for by doing some pregeneralization.

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/featurepregen.html

Comment: +1 - very nice extension. Would be nice to have a MapServer equivalent..

Answer (score 3):

Using the OL [cluster strategy](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster.html), you can simplify the representation (for users) but the amount of data transfered will **not** be lower, because the clusterization is done on the client side.

See also, the [documentation page](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.7/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Cluster-js.html).

(I don't know about available options on the server side)

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken but the cluster strategy appears to be for point data. I have complex polygon data which I would like simplify.

Comment: This wouldn't reduce network traffic as all the points would be needed to cluster client side.

Comment: @geographika > that's what I wanted to say, but as you can guess I forgot the negation in my sentence (repared now)! It is still a good way to enhanced readability for final users

Comment: @Mr_Chimp > no equivalent for polygons, indeed

Answer (score 3):

Some possible solutions:

- Do you really need the data in a vector format? If the large complex polygons are just for reference then they'll be fine as WMS / images. If you can simplify them then you probably don't need the geometry anyway.
- You can pass in a generalisation parameter to a map layer through a custom paramter, and use this to simplify geometry. This thread is about MapServer, but I assume something similar can be done with GeoServer - http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/WFS-Server-Control-output-by-scale-td2279383.html
- Also referenced in the above thread, you can store the datasets presimplified for different scales and hide/show them in your map as needed
- Make sure you have [gZip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) compression turned on at your webserver as this will shrink GML/XML files to at least half the size

Comment: I definitely need them in vector format as I want to be able to click on them to get further information as well as edit the polygons (though obviously I only want to be able to edit the true shapes, not the simplified versions, which might be a little tricky).

Comment: @mr_chimp - you can use the WMS GetFeatureInfo request to return just the geometry and attributes for the feature under a mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is that the WFS is 'heavy' (its GML output is verbose by nature), my advice is that instead you use Well-Known Text (WKT), if possible. I guess that OpenLayers' BBox strategy is "compatible" with WKT.