# A lot of pointers to load on map-A better solution

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, web-mapping, clustering

I have to project a lot of points present in my Database say more than 100000. I heard that using geoserver is a better solution as it can render any number of points and from http://swingley.appspot.com/maps/olpts it is almost confirmed that I cannot use the normal code to project many points. I recently heard about cluster strategy that is present in OpenLayers and I think it can help me but I am not sure.

Can anyone help me about the better solution of these two GEOSERVER or CLUSTER strategy and reasons why one is preferred over the other? Remember I have to display many layers on the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [that thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9228/simplify-geoserver-wfs-output/9242#9242), jdeolive pointed us to a [generalization geoserver extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/featurepregen.html). I really think you should give a try to this.

Regarding the OL cluster strategy, it can be use to enhanced user visualization but **it will not reduce the amount of transferred data** since the clusterization is done on the client side.

Comment: Since OL is client side technology, it will not reduce the amount of data transfered. However, if he were doing server-side clustering, it would help greatly :)

Comment: IMO, Using OL cluster strategy with 100000 points is not an option. Possibly hang client browser.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds that you are using the word *project*, to mean *render/display* (or do you actually want to do projections in the sense of changing coordinate systems?)

If it is the first, clustering is a good visualization technique to reduce the amount of data that you either transfer over the wire or display on the screen.

But if all you want to do is display a lot of data from various layers - and this data is not changing too often, you should start by looking at Geoserver's [GeoWebCache](http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/) functionality